# Python could not recognition the SnowNLP

Tags: python

I use Pycharm to write code.

```
import importlib,sys
importlib.reload(sys)
from snownlp import SnowNLP
import  pandas as pd
text=pd.read_excel(u'comment-label.xlsx',header=0)    #读取excel表格数据
text0=text.iloc[:,0]                                  #提取所有数据
text1=[i.decode('utf-8')for i in text0]               #转码


sent=[SnowNLP(i).sentiments for i in text1]          #遍历每条评论进行预测
newsenti=[]
for i in sent:
    if(i>=0.5):
        newsenti.append(1)
    else:
        newsenti.append(-1)
        text['predict'] = newsenti
counts=0
for j in range(len(text.iloc[:,0])):                  #遍历所有标签，将预测标签和实际标签进行比较，相同则判断正确。
    if text.iloc[j,2]==text.iloc[j,1]:
        counts+=1
print (u"准确率为:%f"%(float(counts)/float(len(text))))            #输出本次预测的准确率
```

and it returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\程序软件\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\程序软件\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "D:\程序软件\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:\程序软件\pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/程序软件/pycharmProject/test/Sentiment_analysis/assessment.py", line 4, in <module>
    from snownlp import SnowNLP
  File "D:\程序软件\pycharmProject\test\Sentiment_analysis\snownlp.py", line 4, in <module>
    from snownlp import SnowNLP
ImportError: cannot import name 'SnowNLP'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

but i have installed the package 'snownlp'
['snownlp ' installing path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6x9d.jpg)

yesterday I could debug the other code with the `from snownlp import SnowNLP` well  and didn't see this  error, but now the other code meets the same error too.

And I reinstall the snownlp package in  Pycharm but,it doesn't work.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
importlib.reload(sys)
```

It's  not doing anything but causing problems I think.

Also you probably don't need to import importlib at all...

Finally stop importing snownlp inside snownlp. I think that's the main problem now.

Comment: In what line does the error say you are importing snownlp. Maybe save the file or restart the console (if you are running it from console). It should work unless you have tampered with the snownlp file.

Comment: I knew it. After lookin at the error again, it looks like you are importing snownlp right inside snownlp. You can't do this. Remove the import and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your python file name 'snownlp' same as the library name.You should just rename your file.